# What is the REST way of treating HTTP method and a resource

Tags: rest, http

Over HTTP, the request line contains the request method, and a reference to a resource. The server can treat the request in two ways

1. With method X, the following resources are available
2. On resource X, the following methods are allowed

In case of (1), the method acts like an outer namespace.

In case of (2), the resource acts like an outer namespace.

How to do this following the REST convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to do this following the REST convention.

REST doesn't care about implementation details; so long as your implementation interprets the semantics of the request the same way everyone else does (aka uniform interface), the underlying implementation doesn't matter.

---

That said: if we receive a request for a resource that we recognize, but the HTTP method on the request doesn't make sense for that specific resource, we'll normally want to send a `405 Method Not Allowed` response rather than a `404 Not Found` response.

Implementations of this behavior that branch on resource first will probably be easier to maintain in the long run.  REST doesn't care, but the human beings that need to support your implementation may care quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

After searching the internet I found this article [REST endpoints: verb or noun?](https://ppbruna.medium.com/rest-endpoints-verb-or-noun-2a2c4c4c9243), and also [What Is REST?](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html). Apparently I should find the resource first, and then check the HTTP method.